# hyphen in python argument parser

Tags: python

i am going though one python script and found this line for passing arguments. I want to know what is the need to repeat same arguments with -daily and --daily

```
 parser.add_argument("-daily", "--daily", action="store_true", default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows the argument to be passed with either one or two hyphens, that's all. Normally, the one hyphen form would be abbreviated (e.g. `-d` or `--daily`), but it can be used like this to be hyphen count agnostic. Or you could just omit one and require exactly one or exactly two hyphens.

Comment: Please also notice that this interferes with the common practice to contract single letter arguments like `-a -b -c` becoming `-abc`.